# Prisma Mongodb can't create a user model

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma

**So I am using Prisma for the first time and my provider is [`mongodb`](https://mongodb.com/) and when I want to create a model it throws me an error**

```
Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation:


  Prisma needs to perform transactions, which requires your MongoDB server to be run 
as a replica set. https://pris.ly/d/mongodb-replica-set
```

**I am using Prisma in a [nextjs](https://nextjs.org) app and I put the code inside the API pages**

My DATABASE_URL is  `mongodb://localhost:27017/threadzees`

Code :

```js
await prisma.user.create({
      data: {
        username,
        email,
        avatar: "1",
        createdAt: new Date(),
      },
    });
```

**How do I fix this issue?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I'm Running Mongodb 4+ version I solved it as below**
As the error describes you need to create a replica. Either you can use cloud based Mongo or locally you can create a replica like below.

```
# Open new terminal execute below command
 mongod --port=27001 --dbpath=. --replSet=rs0
# Open another terminal window execute below command
mongo.exe
# Then below command
rs.initiate( {    _id : "rs0", members: [ { _id: 0, host: "localhost:27001" } ] })
# your new connection String
mongodb://localhost:27001
```

1. --dbpath : Is your data path directory (above command points to current directory)
2. --replSet=rs0 : Replica name
3. Read more @ https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the local mongodb service, locate the mongod.cfg file (usually in `Program File\MongoDB\Server\[version number]\bin`) and configure it to use replica set. Add the following lines:

```
replication:
   replSetName: rs0
```

Then launch `mongosh` from a terminal and initiate the replica set servers using `rs.initiate()`. Your code should be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "prisma": "2.26.0" and "@prisma/client": "2.26.0" instead of your current version. They don`t need a replica set.
Also you have to use @default(dbgenerated()) instead of @default(auto()) both with "npx prisma@2.26.0 generate" for this old version.